# Simple question on ReplaceAll funciton

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

This is working.

```
Array[f, {3, 3}] /. f -> g

{{g[1, 1], g[1, 2], g[1, 3]}, {g[2, 1], g[2, 2], 
  g[2, 3]}, {g[3, 1], g[3, 2], g[3, 3]}}
```

This is working.

```
Array[f, {3, 3}] /. f -> List

{{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{3, 
   1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}}}
```

Why is this not working?

```
Array[f, {3, 3}] /. f -> #1 + #2 &

Array[f, {3, 3}] /. f -> #1 + #2 &
```

Comment: could you show what is the output  you expect?  You are using a pure function in pattern replacement where you should be using Map.  But if you give what the output you expected, may be this will help.

Comment: Try `Array[f, {3, 3}] /. f -> (#1 + #2 &)`